# asdfghjkl; plugin, still alive?

Tags: linux, windows, firefox, vim, vimperator

i really love the concept of vimperator and i found this plugin pretty awesome: [asdghfkl plugin](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins/blob/master/asdfghjkl.js). It's supposed to remap the numbers to letters for the Hint prompt.

Thing is I tested it and it's not working at all. I tried to change the keybindings as the description said. Any ideas ? Do you think this is still compatible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess you are using a firefox version 20 or higher.

From the README.

```
Note: Master is valid only for versions Firefox 19.* and lower.

For versions Firefox 20.* and higher, please check the branch 3.6
```

[Link to branch 3.6](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins/tree/3.6)

Comment: I already tested this branch, but it didn't work either.
I'm hitting space in hint mode and nothing changes. Thanks anyway

Comment: nevermind, it's working, for a reason a thought the prompt was changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to ditch Vimperator and install Pentadactyl. It supports the letter hints out of the box (no plugins needed).